# How to Show only one Component when UIPickerView have Multiple Components?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two Componenets in UIPickerView. One is for country and another is for city. I want to show only one component when clicked on Country Button and another one will show when clicked on the City Button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!


    var pickerData = [["India", "Pakistan", "Bangladesh", "USA", "Afganistan", "Russia", "Nepal", "Bhutan"], ["Chandigarh", "Punjab", "Ludhiana", "Amritsar", "Shimal", "Una"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPicker.isHidden = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       // print(pickerData[row])
        showCountry.text = pickerData[component][row]

    }

    @IBAction func showCountry(_ sender: Any) {
        myPicker.isHidden = false
    }
```

For Now when I  click on country, it shows both components but I just want to show one componenet in pickerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by just handling it in conditions as requirement

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var pickerData = [["India", "Pakistan", "Bangladesh", "USA", "Afganistan", "Russia", "Nepal", "Bhutan"], ["Chandigarh", "Punjab", "Ludhiana", "Amritsar", "Shimal", "Una"]]
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
    var check : Int = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         myPicker.isHidden = true
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if check == 1 {
            return 1
        }
        else
        {
           return 1
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if check == 1 {
           return pickerData[0][row]
        }
        else
        {
             return pickerData[1][row]
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // print(pickerData[row])
       // showCountry.text = pickerData[component][row]

    }

    @IBAction func showCountry(_ sender: Any) {
        check = 1
        myPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        myPicker.isHidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func showcity(_ sender: Any) {
        check = 2
        myPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        myPicker.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanx for your ans its really helpfull for me :) and its also work like charm :).. and there is liitle few mistakes in ur code but i fixed them... but still thanx a lot uh saved my time and this ans is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

If you want select one picker and country and city

```
numberOfComponents
```

should be **2**

or if you want select one picker and country than select again to city

```
numberOfComponent
```

should be **1**

but careful this state

//e.g

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!


var pickerData = [["India", "Pakistan", "Bangladesh", "USA", "Afganistan", "Russia", "Nepal", "Bhutan"], ["Chandigarh", "Punjab", "Ludhiana", "Amritsar", "Shimal", "Una"]]

var isSelectingCountry = true

var selectedCountry: String!
var selectedCity: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPicker.isHidden = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[isSelectingCountry ? 0 : 1].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let index = isSelectingCountry ? 0 : 1
    return pickerData[index][row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // print(pickerData[row])
    //showCountry.text = pickerData[component][row]
    if isSelectingCountry {
        isSelectingCountry = false
        selectedCountry = pickerData[0][row]
    } else {
        selectedCity = pickerData[1][row]
    }
}

@IBAction func showCountry(_ sender: Any) {
    // if you want reset picker for start with country uncomment below line
    //isSelectingCountry = true
    myPicker.isHidden = false

}
```

and you can use **selectedCity** and **selectedCountry**

Comment: sir my components are shows 2 but what i want to show only one component like I have 2 componets one is for country and another is for city so when i clik on country button then only country componenets will shows not city component

Comment: thanx for your ans I just want to show componenets when someone clicked on button so didselect row is required?

Comment: If you want keep selectedRow, yes is required

Comment: thanx sir ur code also work fine but another one is acceptable and thanx for ur time :) and ssory my reputaion is low so i cant able to give uh vote

Comment: No problem, have fun!